# NodeJS HMAC Hash Creation

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to follow part of a tutorial for an API written in PHP. They show the following example:

```
$public = 'JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD';
$private = 'E6X9FyZvMFeJbqtq.IwjlTuR.MKDoicB';

$url = 'https://pterodactyl.local/api/admin/users';
$body = '';

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $url . $body, $private, true);

return $public . '.' . base64_encode($hmac);

// Should return the string below:
//
// JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD.wgIxj+V8RHgIetcQg2lRM0PRSH/y5M21cPz9zVhfFaQ=
```

But my method doesn't return the proper value. Instead it returns the following:

```
JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD./RKZS3U2FKfEt7/tEks4vWwyS+89lL+k8aEGO8NJWuo=
```

Here is my code:

```
    hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', private_key);
    hmac.write(url+body);
    hmac.end();
    hash = hmac.read().toString('base64');
    console.log(hash);
```

EDIT: I think the example they provided was invalid because as everyone is saying my code is almost identical and the PHP code outputs a different value then it said it should in the documentation.

Comment: *"Should return the string below"* - Well, it doesn't. Your PHP code and your node.js code are currently equivalent. Perhaps you should check whether your PHP code is actually operating how you think it does.

Comment: This is not how public-key crypto works. HMAC is a symmetric component.

Comment: @ArtjomB.how is this not how public key crypto works?

Comment: As I said, no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: @ArtjomB. It is a good thing that this isn't public key crypto. This is just a client authentication header. It has nothing to do with keys if you read the question properly.

Comment: Yes, I did. You have `$public` and `$private` key variables. Which suggests that you think this is some sort of public-key crypto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so, i used this tool [writephponline](http://www.writephponline.com/) to run this php code:

```
$public = 'JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD';
$private = 'E6X9FyZvMFeJbqtq.IwjlTuR.MKDoicB';

$url = 'https://pterodactyl.local/api/admin/users';
$body = '';

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $url . $body, $private, true);

echo $public . '.' . base64_encode($hmac);
```

and returns:

```
JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD./RKZS3U2FKfEt7/tEks4vWwyS+89lL+k8aEGO8NJWuo=
```

So i used that as a parameter, then i made a little nodejs script:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var public = 'JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD';

var private = 'E6X9FyZvMFeJbqtq.IwjlTuR.MKDoicB';

var url = 'https://pterodactyl.local/api/admin/users';

var body = '';

var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', private).update(url+body).digest('base64');

console.log(public + '.' + hmac);
```

and returns:

```
JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD./RKZS3U2FKfEt7/tEks4vWwyS+89lL+k8aEGO8NJWuo=
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am prefer use `crypto-js` library of crypto standards. This library is keep maintaining.

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js')

const public = 'JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD'
const private = 'E6X9FyZvMFeJbqtq.IwjlTuR.MKDoicB'
const url = 'https://pterodactyl.local/api/admin/users'
const body = ''

const hmac = crypto.HmacSHA256(url + body, private).toString(crypto.enc.Base64)

console.log(public + '.' + hmac)
// Print value:
// JkAFq7M47kLN0xVD./RKZS3U2FKfEt7/tEks4vWwyS+89lL+k8aEGO8NJWuo=
```

Comment: Meh the one i'm using is built in and maintained by the NodeJS gods themselves.